# How to override php.ini timeout for imap_timeout functionality with secure POP3 servers

Tags: php, imap, pop3

The PHP IMAP Library doesn't have built in ways to change the imap_timeout function for secure pop3 connections.  I'm looking to build this functionality so I can set timeout to 1 second for connections for secure pop3 servers, but I'm just not sure where I would start to learn about overriding the php.ini command within a PHP function.  Any ideas?

> imap_timeout(1, ) works fine
>   for pop3 connections, **but apparently
>   not for pop3s (ssl, port 995)**
>   connections, where the default socket
>   timeout still applies. This applies to
>   php 4.3.10, not tested on other
>   versions.

---

> We looked into the source to find out
>   what this function actually does and
>   how to use it. **The function overrides
>   the default_socket_timeout setting
>   from your php.ini file**
>
> You can retrieve the current timeout
>   length for each timeout type by
>   calling the function as:
>
> imap_timeout(timeout_type);
>        or   imap_timeout(timeout_type,-1);
>
> You can set the timeout length for any
>   of the timeout types by setting the
>   timeout value to a number of seconds.
>
> imap_timeout(timeout_type,);
>
> The timeout types are as follows:
>
> 1: Open 2: Read 3: Write 4: Close
>
> It does not appear that the close type
>   has been implemented.

Source:  https://students.kiv.zcu.cz/doc/php5/manual/cs/function.imap-timeout.php.html

Comment: Have you tried `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 999)` ?

Comment: I want to get timeout to 1 second for only pop3 connections, but I'm worried it will timeout the entire function.

Comment: @Havenard ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 2); doesn't work for me.

Comment: I am amazed that this is still a problem for me in PHP5.3.   Have you found a solution elsewhere?

Comment: @coderama - if this is a problem for you, feel free to make any other clarifications in the comments. For example, what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: it was reported as a bug over a year ago: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61846 ; short of fixing this bug in php you best chance is probably to use an alternate imap library

Answer (score 6):

use the `default_socket_timeout`

here is small demonstration to override default configuration.

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 2);
// your socket based code here

// restore to the default socket timeout
ini_restore('default_socket_timeout');
```